# Is it possible to create a md-chip with a slim border?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

It is possible to set a border or background-color for an Angular `md-chip`? I want background color to be whatever color (say, white) and then a slim black border.

Comment: Is `md-chip` part of a material design library? If so, could you provide a link to that library? Also a sketch of what you want, or a sample of the code you already have, would be useful. You might like to review the instructions on the best way to ask questions on Stack overflow. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

OK here is the [link to the Angular reference page on `md-chip`s](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/chips).

Here is the CSS to add a black border and white background.

```
 .md-chips md-chip {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

You may need to add `!important` in order to override the default styles, like so:

```
 .md-chips md-chip {
    border: 1px solid #000 !important;
    background-color: #fff !important;
}
```